# Descargar .docx - b64 a archivo

Tags: javascript, base64

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, que descarga un documento codificado en 64 de tipo docx, al cargar un archivo ligero si descarga el archivo:

```
downloadFile(index) {
const linkSource = 'data:application/msword;base64,' + index.documento;
const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
const fileName = 'sample.doc';
downloadLink.href = linkSource;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
}
```

Al intentar codificar un nuevo archivo (intente con uno de aproximadamente 7.7MB), y al descargar me arroja un error en la descarga "error de red". Sera que estoy aplicando algo mal.
Por cierto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997848/angular-6-unable-to-convert-base64-to-pdf aqui tome el ejemplo.
Alguna idea de como descargar el archivo .docx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método que utilizas arroja un `Error de red` porque al parecer Chrome no soporta tanto peso para descargar a través de `base64`. La solución que se me ocurre es que utilices un `Blob` para descargar.

Tendrías que convertir tu `string` de `base64` primero a `Blob` y posteriormente descargarte ese `Blob`. Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
function downloadBlob(blob, filename){
    if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var elem = window.document.createElement('a');
        elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        elem.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
        elem.click();
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
    }
}

function downloadDocument(strBase64, filename) {
    let url = "data:application/msword;base64," + strBase64;  
    var documento = null;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(function(blob) {
      downloadBlob(blob, filename);
    });
}
```

La llamada sería:

```
downloadDocument('aqui tu base64', 'prueba.docx');
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta.